# Filtering columns in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe with the following column.

```
  A
 55B
 <lhggkkk>
 66c
 dggfhhjjjj
```

I need to filter the records which start with number(such as 55B and 66C) separately and the others separately. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['A'] = ['55B','<lhggkkk>','66c','dggfhhjjjj']
df['B'] = df['A'].apply(lambda x:x[0].isdigit())
print(df)
            A      B
0         55B   True
1   <lhggkkk>  False
2         66c   True
3  dggfhhjjjj  False
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to check if the first number is digit then boolen index i.e

```
mask =  df['A'].str[0].str.isdigit()
one = df[mask]
two = df[~mask]

print(one,'\n',two)

  A
0  55B
2  66c 
             A
1   <lhggkkk>
3  dggfhhjjjj
```

Answer (score 0):

To check first string is digit or not:

```
df['A'].str[0].str.isdigit()
```

So:

```
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np
```

df:

```
-----------------
    |          A         
-----------------
 0  |        55B
 1  |  <lhggkkk>
 2  |        66c
 3  | dggfhhjjjj

df['Result'] = np.where(df['A'].str[0].str.isdigit(), 'Numbers', 'Others')
```

df:

```
----------------------------
    |          A |    Result
----------------------------
 0  |        55B |   Numbers
 1  |  <lhggkkk> |    Others
 2  |        66c |   Numbers
 3  | dggfhhjjjj |    Others
```